# What Webserver Do I Need For A Social App

Tags: php, webserver, vps, android, node-js

I am making a social application that its base work is like twitter.

When user opens app,it fetches data(texts and images) from server and listitems will be filled and users can be followed and etc.

I think number of users for it is up to 500,000 and i want to use `node.js` for server side because it's faster that php.

How should i find best `webserver(VPS,dedicated,...)` for this application?

Comment: Just start with a small package, and upgrade when needed. No need to worry about that now, just make sure your _code_ can upscale. You'll notice hardware bottlenecks early enough to fix'm

Comment: We don't accept specific questions about web hosting here.  They tend to attract opinions and spam.  Instead we have a single question with general information about how to choose your web server.